# Is the sequence 1-1-2-3-Exit possible in the following Markov reward process?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

Is the sequence 1-1-2-3-Exit possible in the following Markov reward process?
The probability of transitioning from state 1 to itself is 0.

Source: https://maelfabien.github.io/rl/RL_2/#markov-process-mp

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, and you correctly explained why.